Is there a way to add a feature/column to an SQL table from a pandas dataframe?
I have a pandas dataframe with two columns, PaymentID and WasDenied. I want to add that WasDenied column to my SQL table "Payments" by merging on the PaymentID column. Is there any way to do that?
I'm familiar with pandas .to_sql() but I don't think the replace or append options in the if_exists parameter will help because I'm not looking to append or replace, I'm looking to merge/join, although I could be wrong. I'm using SQLite and MS SQL so if the answer is different depending on the database, let me know.
Payment Table in SQL:



PaymentID
Payment Type
Payment Amount




123
Credit Card
$100.00


456
Cash
$25.50


456
Cash
$25.50


789
Bank Transfer
$500.75


101
Debit Card
$32.14


101
Debit Card
$35.20



WasDenied table in Pandas:



PaymentID
WasDenied




123
True


456
False


789
False


101
True



Resulting updated Payments table that I'd like to see:



PaymentID
Payment Type
Payment Amount
WasDenial




123
Credit Card
$100.00
True


456
Cash
$25.50
False


456
Cash
$25.50
False


789
Bank Transfer
$500.75
False


101
Debit Card
$32.14
True


101
Debit Card
$35.20
True



df = pd.DataFrame([[123, True],[456, False], [789, False], [101, True]], columns=['PaymentID', 'WasDenial'])
df


I don't think to_sql can do that directly. Would you consider creating a temporary table with your df.to_sql and then running an update containing join query to update your payments table?

Sure. I'm just looking for the efficient way to add that column to the SQL table. What would the code to that look like?

When you say "add a column", are you talking about changing the table in the database? (If so, you need to specify which DBMS you're using, such as SQLite, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc) Or just creating a result set from that table, with an additional column derived from a dataframe? (If so, please show the results you require in your question.)

Changing the table in the database so that it now has the new "WasDenied" column. But I'll add the results I'm looking for to my question.

That's DMS specific. So, please tag which DBMS you're using.  Also, how many rows tend to be in your dataframe?

Why the  tag? Is this really a SQL language question? (I see no SQL above. Is a SQL answer expected?)

@MatBailie, a few 100 thousand

@jarlh, I thought it was possible and even likely that the correct answer here is to use some combination of pandas and SQL. So for example, pandas.to_sql( some_temp_table) and then writing SQL to merge the two

Third time lucky...  That's DBMS specific. Please tag which DBMS you're using.

Perhaps you're right, I don't know.

@MatBailie either SQLite or MS SQL

Which one. Please go to the SQL tag's page and actually read the description.

@MatBailie, do you want me to post the question twice? One for each Database? For now, let's just say SQLite.

There's no "let's just say" because SQLite is a weakly typed database with very limited features while SQL Server is one of the big three, with a lot of performance features that matter. Pandas isn't a database tool and the scripts generated by to_sql are rudimentary at best. If you use a server-based database you'll have to modify ALL the generated columns, because the selected types and lengths are almost always wrong. Never mind generating proper indexes, constraints etc. That's not a problem with SQLite though because it has no types, no field lengths, limited performance features

SQLite has it's own benefits in it's simplicity, but I'm not here to discuss my use of databases. I asked a question regarding a simple merge from a pandas dataframe to an SQL table and I didn't realize it would be so hard to answer...

Because the majority of your task is on a remote server with different language, and each DBMS has a different language.  The pandas dataframe aspect of your question is almost incidental.

I appreciate your answer but it's not incidental at all considering I'm asking what is the best way to take it from a pandas dataframe to an SQL database. Plus, in this case, the SQL language is mostly similar for both SQLite and SQL Server except with some minor changes due to differences in data types. I came here looking for help because of my lack of knowledge, not to have every little detail of my question scrutinized unnecessarily. Maybe someone could have gone down the all pandas route by suggesting a SELECT * query, merging with pandas, and then .to_sql(if_exists="replace").

If your intention is to handle the logic from your python scripts. You can try the following steps:

Turn your df into a temporary table
Update the Payments table through a join with the temporary table
Drop the temporary table

Here's how it would look considering SQLite as your target database:
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# Assuming you have a DataFrame named 'df' with columns 'PaymentID' and 'WasDenied'

# Create a temporary table with the new column
conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
df.to_sql('temp_table', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Assuming 'PaymentID' is the primary key in the Payments table
update_query = """
UPDATE Payments
SET WasDenied = (
    SELECT t.WasDenied
    FROM temp_table t
    WHERE t.PaymentID = Payments.PaymentID
)
"""

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(update_query)
conn.commit()

# Drop the temporary table if it's no longer needed
drop_query = "DROP TABLE temp_table"
cursor.execute(drop_query)

conn.close()

I would personally use SQLAlchemy in such cases, but the choice is totally dependent on your project and requirements. If SQLAlchemy fits into your solution you can try the following code instead:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('your_database_connection_string')

df.to_sql('temp_table', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

update_query = """
UPDATE Payments
SET WasDenied = (
    SELECT t.WasDenied
    FROM temp_table t
    WHERE t.PaymentID = Payments.PaymentID
)
"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(update_query)

drop_query = "DROP TABLE temp_table"
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(drop_query)


SQLite doesn't have a boolean datatype. Instead, TRUE and FALSE are synonyms for 1 and 0.
So, add the column as an Integer, defaulting to 0, then update its value from another table.
ALTER TABLE payment
   ADD COLUMN WasDenial INT
   DEFAULT 0
;

UPDATE payment
   SET WasDenial = 1
   WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT *
        FROM xxx
       WHERE xxx.PaymentID = payment.PaymentID
         AND xxx.WasDenial = 1
   )
;

When creating table xxx (from the dataframe), I recommend filtering to only the TRUE rows.  That way you don't need to expend resources on the WasDenial column, or the FALSE rows.

I assume the other part of your answer is to write df.to_sql(xxx), correct?
